# Free web search API or web search logs

Tags: search, dataset, logging, web

For university research I need a lot of web query examples and the relative resources returned by some search engine, for which I have 2 possibilities: either collect them from a search engine or search some available data set.

I know that Google offers an API but I know that it only permits 100 free queries per day.

Can anyone give me other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

There are several free query log datasets available, but they are all older to the best of my knowledge.

For English query logs:

- [AOL Query Logs](http://www.gregsadetsky.com/aol-data/)
- [MSN Query Logs](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/nickcr/wscd09/) -- You may need to request access to this, but should be available for research purposes.

Alternatively, you could write your own scraper for Google or other search engine to bypass their API restrictions, but that's a morally gray area, and I know Google will start presenting you with captchas after a few hundred queries.